# Recreating the Animation Nodes FCurve Animation Offset Template

Tags: animation, animation-nodes, fcurves, instances

Hi i've been trying to find a way to create and control traffic (thats also flying) in a large futuristic city scene. To do this I'm trying to re-create an old animation nodes template that I feel will solve the problem but i keep coming up short. Does anyone know the layout of the subprogram for this video? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SsrQk1kiGF0&t=75s

Answer (score 1):

Lets say we have a cube with some f-curves that controls its location.

[image: Animation]

And we have an array of spheres that we want to transform based on the f-curves of the cube with an offset it time.

[image: Array Of Spheres]

What we are going to do is create a loop that evaluates the x, y and z f-curves at multiple offset values, combine the result in a vector and append it. The offsets shall be of uniform range generated using the *Float Range* node.

[image: Loop]

By adding the evaluated locations to the locations of the spheres, we get the result you are looking for.

[image: Final]